# Vertigo doesn't work properly with evil motions

Tags: evil, motion

I'm using [vertigo](https://github.com/noctuid/vertigo.el) with evil in the following way:

```
(evil-define-motion vertigo-j (count)
  "Evil vertigo motion. Count has no effect."
  (vertigo--jump #'evil-next-line "Jump down: "))
```

...and I map it to `j` with:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "j") #'vertigo-j)
(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "j") #'vertigo-j)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "j") #'vertigo-j)
```

It works well enough for normal motion, but **when I try to delete some lines** (with `dj`), **something strange happens**. I go from:

```
1  It was on ▊a dreary
2  night of November that I
3  beheld the accomplishment
4  of my toils.  With an
5  anxiety that almost
6  amounted to agony, I
7  collected the instruments...
```

(where `▊` is *point*), and, by pressing `dj` and `f` (delete down 4 lines), I get:

```
1  It was on ▊at almost
2  amounted to agony, I
3  collected the instruments...
```

**What should have happened** is that the *whole* of the first line was deleted, along with the whole of line 5:

```
1  ▊amounted to agony, I
2  collected the instruments...
```

**What is incorrect about my remapping, and how can I fix it to get the desired behaviour?**

Comment: When defining a motion (`evil-define-motion`), Evil's info manual (section 5.1) shows that you can also set its type, e.g. `type: line` so that "the range is expanded to linewise positions" - if that's what you want (see also the 'block' type). I didn't test this, but I think that's what you're after. And if we're here, perhaps you also want to set `:jump t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining a motion (`evil-define-motion`), Evil's info manual (section 5.1) shows that you can also set its type, e.g. `type: line` so that "the range is expanded to linewise positions".

This seems to work:

```
(evil-define-motion vertigo-j (count)
  :type line
  :jump t
  "Evil vertigo motion. Count has no effect."
    (vertigo-jump-down))

;; example mapping
(define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd "g j") #'vertigo-j)
```

In my case, I couldn't even use `vertigo--jump` (?), so I simply relied on the example provided by the plugin author.

Now, something like `dgjaa` will delete entire lines. Using `vgjaad` will not delete entire lines though - but this is OK, since with visual mode, the user controls the type of selection (so, you can use `Vgjaad` instead).

Comment: You have to `(require 'vertigo)` to get `vertigo--jump`, as it's not autoloaded.

Comment: However, your answer fixes the problem perfectly!

Comment: Glad it worked - I edited it a little to add the bit of useful info from the original comment.